# Disable "httpErrors" element for a specific path

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, web-config

I'm having trouble with [`httpErrors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpErrors/) element in Web.config.

I decided to use httpErrors element to handle http errors and show custom error pages in my (ASP.NET MVC) application. The problem is that I also have an API that I don't want httpErrors element to handle its errors, it has its own custom error responses.

I want it to be disabled when it comes to API.

Is there anything I can do to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution.

We can fix such problems by using the `location` element:

We just have to put the code below in the `configuration` element (the root) of the Web.config:

```
  <location path="api">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

What the `<location>` element actually does is that it overrides the configurations for paths that start with what you put in the path attribute, which in my case is "api". Then what you have to do is disable the `httpErrors`, which can be done by setting the `existingResponse` attribute to `PassThrough`.

I hope this helps.